# Как импортировать excel в django?

Tags: python, django, excel, импорт

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо из файла excel заполнить базу данных
Уже и xlrd пробовал и import-export и django-excel.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from . models import *
from .forms import *
import xlrd

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                    w = form.sheet_by_index(0)
                    s = CadetsSubject(cadet = Cadets.objects.get(id=1), subject = Subject.objects.get(id=1), month = Month.objects.get(id=1),mark = w.c$
                    s.save()
                    handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
                    return HttpResponse("OK", status=200)
```

У меня form даже проверку не проходит и просто ничего не происходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста как быть и через что делать.

Comment: Очень интересная задача, вы нашли на него ответ?

Comment: Да, постараюсь поискать в старых проектах

Comment: Будет супер если сюда в ответ вставишь решение проблемы)

Comment: Использовал django-excel, не знаю с чем я тогда столкнулся, но вроде по инструкции все должно работать